# Javascript function argument error

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using the following function:

```
<body onload="testing(<?php print "'". $_SESSION['data'] . "'"; ?>);">
```

if `$_SESSION['data'] = "My name is function"` then it works fine but

if `$_SESSION['data'] = "Calling jackson's function"` then it gives error.

Can you tell me how can i pass an argument which may contain characters like

```
$_SESSION['data'] = "Calling jackson's function"
```

into the testing function parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape them with `addslashes()`

```
echo "'" . addslashes($_SESSION['data']) . "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
<body onload="testing(<?php print "'". addslashes($_SESSION['data']) . "'"; ?>);">
```